# How direct call the amazon personalize service?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

Good day!
How I can call from the backend(nodejs) the amazon service?

I found library aws-sdk-js, but not sure how to find exact URL of my service.

Moreover, do I need to use S3 to manage input data and output data?
In the Personalize server settings I can find "Batch inference jobs" with inputs for these matter.[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeKCB.png)

Comment: Which particular API call are you attempting to use? See: [Class: AWS.Personalize — AWS SDK for JavaScript](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Personalize.html)

Comment: Hi John, I need to send an array of data from the frontend of my app to the Personalize service and get output. I am not sure which API is the best for me for this purpose.

By the way, I have already set up a Personalize campaign but still don't know about URL which I should access.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with the details of the Personalize service, but the above link shows all the APIs available. I suggest reading through the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/personalize/latest/dg/what-is-personalize.html) or watching [AWS re:Invent 2019: Delight your customers with ML-based personalized recommendations (AIM323) - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XCE3PnGb3As&feature=youtu.be).

Comment: Thanks, I've just wathed the same video :)